# Flutter - ListView not updating after provider call notifyListeners?

Tags: listview, flutter, dart, provider, rxdart

I built up my App with Rxdart-provider pattern(http request by dio). When I get data from server ,my ListView not rebuilt after I updated its data list by call `addAll()` method ;However,when I tried `dataList = newDataList`,it works!The ListView updated successfully.Could someone tell me why,please.

Provider:

```
class ServicesVM extends BaseProvider {
  final ServicesRepository _model;
  List<ServiceEntity> serviceList = [];
  List<Goods> currGoods = [];

  ServicesVM(this._model);

  void getServices() {
    addSubscription(
      _model.getServices()
        .doOnData((data) {

        //now work 
        serviceList.addAll((data.data as List).map(
            (ele) => ServiceEntity.fromJson(ele)
        ));

        //works 
        /*List<ServiceEntity> temp = [];
        temp.addAll((data.data as List).map(
            (ele) => ServiceEntity.fromJson(ele)
        ));
        serviceList=temp;*/

        serviceList.asMap().forEach((i,v) {
          v.selected = i == 0;
        });
        currGoods = serviceList[0].goods;
      }).doOnDone(() {
        serviceList.forEach(print);
        notifyListeners();
      }).listen((_) {})
    );
```

ListView:

```
Container(
                  width: 99.dp,
                  height: double.infinity,
                  color: Color(Iro.gray4),
                  child: Selector <ServicesVM, List<ServiceEntity>>(
                    selector: (context,provider) => provider.serviceList,
                    builder: (context,value,child){
                      return  ListView.separated(
                        separatorBuilder: _getSeparator,
                        itemBuilder: (context,index) {
                          return _getLabelItem(index,value[index]);
                        },
                        itemCount: value.length,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been racing to 50 reputation to answer this. I've had been stuck on the same problem for a few days. Use ListView.builder(). The reason this works is because Flutter uses immutable objects. So although the underlying data changes, ListView does not repaint.